# Linq expression returns null

Tags: c#, linq, xamarin, lambda

I added a search bar into my memo Xamarin app. I use this event handler to get the memo list when the text is changed:

```
private void SearchBar_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MemoList.ItemsSource = GetMemo(e.NewTextValue);
    }
```

The handler calls `GetMemo` function but when I have a value in `searchText` variable the function returns null and I don't know why.

```
ObservableCollection<Memo> GetMemo(string searchText = null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText))
            return _memos;

        return _memos.Where(c => c.Title.StartsWith(searchText)) as ObservableCollection<Memo>;

    }
```

Is something wrong with the Lambda expression or with the Linq expression ?

I have to say that the function returns correctly when I don't pass any argument to it.

Comment: The result of `Where` probably isn't a `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: `.Where(...)` returns `IEnumerable<Memo>`. You need to make a new `ObservableCollection` from the IEnumerable.

Comment: Did you debug into it? Whats the result of the first evaluation of 'c.Title.StartsWith(searchText)'

Comment: The result of `Where` is a `IEnumerable` but I cast it as `ObservableCollection`

Comment: If a cast is invalid, `as` won't throw a cast exception, it will just return null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
return new ObservableCollection<Memo>(_memos.Where(c => c.Title.StartsWith(searchText));
```

You have to wrap the ObservableCollection around the IEnumerable result from your linq expression. Just pass the IEnumerable result as a ObservableCollection constructor parameter.

Comment: Ugh, I'm 2 minutes late... :)